# Update all Python files via Linux command

Tags: find, sed

In my original Python files I have the following:

```
from official.utils.flags import _base
```

I need to change it to:

```
from utils.flags import _base
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── trainer
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── task.py
    ├── task_eager.py
    ├── dataset.py
    └── utils
```

All my Python files live under utils folder. I tried:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i -e "s/from official./from /g" {} +
```

But I see a bunch of new files created:

```
test.py             test.py.py          test.py.py.py           test.py.py.py.py        test.py.py.py.py.py     test.py.py.py.py.py.py
test.py-e           test.py.py-e            test.py.py.py-e         test.py.py.py.py-e      test.py.py.py.py.py-e       test.py.py.py.py.py.py-e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest removing the `-e` as it is really not necessary in this case.

Also it is looking like the `-e` is being gobbled up by the `-i` option as the suffix for the backup file will be made as `filename-e` as is shown in your snippet.

This could also happen if you have in your `find` command line a `-i-e` (i.e. forgot the space between the two parameters) instead of what you posted here.